# How to change adapter layout dynamically?

Tags: android, adapter

I have a custom `Adapter` in which I'd like the row layout to change according to the orientation.

I have a function `setOrientation` in which I modify the layout and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, hoping that everything would be reset.

Unfortunately, it seems that it is not because even after `notifyDataSetChanged()`, the `convertView` in the first call of `getView()` is not null, so the layout is not changed.

Is there any way to reset this `convertView`?

```
public class TableRowsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    private int layout;

    private TableRow[] items;

    private class ViewHolder {
        /* some stuff */
    }

    public TableRowsAdapter(Context context, TableRow[] tableRowList)
    {
        super();
        this.items = tableRowList;
        this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

        /* Set default layout to portrait */
        layout = R.layout.table_row;
    }

    public void setOrientation(int orientation){

        if(orientation== Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            layout = R.layout.table_row_land;
        }
        else{
            layout = R.layout.table_row;
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return items.length;
    }

    public TableRow getItem(int position)
    {
        return items[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {

            v = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            /* some stuff */

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        TableRow item = getItem(position);

        /* some stuff */

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe calling `removeAllViews()` on the ListView?

Comment: @MikeM. unfortunately it does not work :(

Comment: I've added explanation and sample code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fastest way:
create a new instance of `TableRowsAdapter` and set it again(make the orientation a constructor parameter).
Example:

```
 public TableRowsAdapter(Context context, TableRow[] tableRowList, int orientation)
  {
    super();
    this.items = tableRowList;
    this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );


    if(orientation== Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        layout = R.layout.table_row_land;
    }
    else{
        layout = R.layout.table_row;
    }

}
```

**The proper way:**

when you `setOrientation`, inflate the new layout and replace convertView with that

Reason: `notifyDatasetChanged()` does not know that you'll replace the layout, so it simply recycles the view thus making `convertView` not null.

In layout `R.layout.table_row_land` and `R.layout.table_row`, add an unique id for the root view,

Example:

id for `R.layout.table_row_land` is `R.id.row_land` and `R.layout.table_row` is `R.id.row_normal`

The root view would become something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/row_normal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >
<!-- the rest of the layout  -->

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's a simple pseudo implementation:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    View v = convertView;

    // check if convertView needs a new layout here
    if (v == null || (v.getId() == R.id.row_normal && layout == R.layout.table_row_land)) {

        v = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        /* some stuff */

        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    TableRow item = getItem(position);

    /* some stuff */

    return v;
}
```

Comment: `v.getId()` does not give the id of the layout, so `v.getId() != layout` is always true and there is no recycling.

Comment: I did something similar, but using a custom tag object: class CustomTagObject {
        public CustomTagObject(ViewHolder viewHolder, int layout){
            this.viewHolder = viewHolder;
            this.layout = layout;
        }
        public ViewHolder viewHolder;
        public int layout;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Create one file `table_row.xml` and put `res/layout` folder and create another file with same name `table_row.xml` which is same as `table_row_land.xml` and put in to `res/layout-land`.

and in adapter set `table_row.xml`

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {

            v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row, parent, false);
        }
        ...
        ...
        ...

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Both of Two Views in your layout(in same XML) and set visibility gone for second layout.inflate it as you have already done, and in get view method make visibility of view according to orientation.

@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
    ViewHolder holder;
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {

        v = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        /* some stuff */

        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    TableRow item = getItem(position);

    /* some stuff */

      if(portrait) {
      // then visiblity of first View or View Group set Visible and
      // visiblity of second View or View Group set Gone
   } else {
   // then visiblity of first View or View Group set GONE and
      // visiblity of second View or View Group set Visible. 
    }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: That would require duplicate fields in the ViewHolder and twice the view count